# Kotlin: Unresolved reference to member function Intellisense suggests?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am learning kotlin in android studio, and I must be making a syntax error.

I have the class:

```
abstract class RoomDB : RoomDatabase() {
   fun getInstance(context:Context) : RoomDB {
       // either finds an existing database or makes a new one
       // returns the database
   }
}
```

Later I am writing the following code:

```
import android.example.app.Database.RoomDB

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var database:RoomDB

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        database = RoomDB.getInstance(this)
    }
}
```

Autocomplete suggests the `getInstance` method; however, when I write this code, I get an unresolved reference error to this method. Any idea why?

Comment: `getInstance` is non-static method in your code you can not call it with class name ..

Comment: I would guess that the `getInstance(Context)` function should actually be declared in the `companion object` of your `RoomDB` class instead of the class itself.

Comment: I changed it to a companion object and that fixed it

Comment: Can someone explain why that fixed it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the suggestion of Slaw I put the method declaration inside of a companion object which fixed the compile errors. I do not understand why that fixed this.

```
abstract class RoomDB : RoomDatabase() {
   companion object {
      fun getInstance(context:Context) : RoomDB {
          // either finds an existing database or makes a new one
          // returns the database
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Functions declared inside a class require an instance of that class to invoke the function on. Functions declared inside a (companion) object can be invoked without an explicit instance, with the syntax just using the object's name. For companion objects, that name is the enclosing class's name. It's sort-of-but-not-quite like the difference between instance methods and static methods in Java, if you're familiar with Java. The reason I say "not quite" is because there is still a singleton instance of the object used behind-the-scenes.

Comment: Whether that helps you or not, I think the best way to understand why the above fix worked is to make sure you fully understand [classes and objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html) in Kotlin.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have enough rep or I would upvote your comments!